# Book with SP Service Application Example

Tags: service-application

In last year I saw book with nice example of SP 2010 Service Application, is anybody know how is this book name?

Answer (score 0):

This excerpt is from the "[Real World SharePoint 2010: Indispensable Experiences from 22 MVPs](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Real-World-SharePoint-2010-Indispensable-Experiences-from-22-MVPs.productCd-0470597135.html)" book. Not sure if you read this one, but it can be quite useful anyway:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193964(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193964%28v=office.14%29.aspx)